# Declared function seen as undefined by IE 11

Tags: javascript

I am having some problems with function declarations in IE. It appears, even if I link the function directly to the window object. I tried switching with document in stead of window, but with no success.

Here is the basic code that I am trying to use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function initChart (id) {...}


    //linking to window object
    window.initChart = initChart;


});
```

As I said, I even tried to link it directly: `window.initchart(id){...}`. More that that, I even included the js file I declared the function inside the body(due to a rumor that says that IE doesn't see function declared in head section)

After that, inside script tags i call `initChart()` with a valid id and I get this error inside the IE console: `'initChart' is undefined`.

```
<script>
    initChart('chart');
</script>
```

The strange thing is that in Chrome, Firefox and Opera has no such problem. Any ideeas?

PS: If this is a duplicate, I did not found the question that covers this.

Comment: In which order are your scripts?

Comment: what do you mean "link" it directly: `window.initchart(id){...}`  You can't do  `window.initchart(id){...}`... you can do  `window.initchart = function(id) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to do `initChart('chart');` inside of the window load event handler (this one or a later added one). Or you can do that in another event handler that you know for sure happens after this window load event handler.

As your code is processed by the browser, it knows to do something on the window load event, which is to set your `window.initChart`.

But then later on you are using it right away, without the event of window load happening yet.

If it doesn't happen in Chrome, I am wondering if everything is loaded, but even so, I'd think your `window.initChart` is set in the next event cycle. (let me try to do some experiments -- you are not doing any of these in the debugger but all inside an HTML file?). But it really shouldn't be ok in Chrome, because the load event handler doesn't occur before your `<script>` tag is parsed and executed, which does `initChart('chart');` already.

But in any event, it is best to follow the event sequence: if you set `window.initChart` on window load event handler, then also only call `window.initChart()` in the same and later added event handler, or in an event handler that happens afterwards.

You can see in the following `HERE 02` happens before `HERE 01`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log("HERE 01");
});

console.log("HERE 02");
```

I am running the following in Chrome and I did get an error as expected:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function foo() {
    console.log("HERE 01");
  }
  window.foo = foo;
});

foo();
```

But this one worked as expected:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  function foo() {
    console.log("HERE 01");
  }
  window.foo = foo;
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  foo();
});
```

Comment: I tried to declare the function outside the windw load listener, but still i get the same error.

Comment: if you declare the function outside the window load handler and before invoking the function, then Chrome can't find it?  That's weird. Are they all in the same HTML file? Any of them external and using `async` or `defer` in the `<script>` tag?

Comment: It appears to be a scope problem. Considering that none of the chart.js library code is not mentioned in the error. And I am sure that IE supports chart.js

Comment: They are all declared in the same html file. And Chrome finds it. I made a mistake while copying the code and putting it outside the load event. I edited that comment. But still I get the same error in IE.

Comment: @AndreiDinuNechita then why don't you also do `window.addEventListener('load', function() { initChart('chart'); });` and make sure you add this handler after the other one

Comment: There is a problem with that theory. I logged the function in the console. IE doesn't even see it. Other browsers do, but IE always prints undefined.

Try the last snippet (the one that works) in IE.

Comment: if you log it in the console, it is normal that Chrome should see it, because it is after the window load event and the handler should have run...   so what happens if each code blocks is inside its own window load handler?

Comment: Same issue. 'undefined'.

Comment: `undefined` in IE 11, and in Chrome, it works?  So if the order of execution of the handlers are not guaranteed, you can also use:  `window.addEventListener('load', function() {   setTimeout(function() { initChart('chart'); }, 0); });`

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently was not the linkage between the function and the window object. In my load event I had some `ES6` string interpolation(something like this: `` console.log(`#${id}`) ``) and IE falls short on this. He doesn't know what to do with it. So as a consequence, my `window.initChart()` was not even compiled. After I commented the code in matter, my `initChart` function was working fine. Thanks for help tho, @nopole!